# convert string to number array in matlab

Tags: arrays, string, matlab

I have a script in which a string of number is entered

```
string='123'
```

or

```
string='9823'
```

I am trying to convert this into an array of the form [a,b,c,d]
e.g from a string of '123' to a numerical array [1,2,3]

Any tips on how to do this?

Comment: OP: Please do not replace your questions with nonsense.

Answer (score 25):

```
str = '123';
num = str - '0';
% num = [1 2 3];
```

Answer (score 0):

use the function `str2num()`

```
str = '123';
str = str2num(str);
```

Note: To verify that i'm correct, type in 'whos str' in the command window,  and check the class. A string has a class, char, and numeric values have a class, double

Comment: Your code produces a 1x1 double, not a 3x1 array of doubles as required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cellstr:

```
cellstr('123')
ans =
{
  [1,1] = 123
}
```