# Matlab - converting the string ('321') to [3,2,1]

Tags: arrays, string, matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [convert string to number array in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046605/convert-string-to-number-array-in-matlab)

I am a new Matlab user. I would like to know how to perform the above. I am completely stumped.

Your time and help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A string in MatLab is just an array of characters.

You can subtract `'0'` to leave the value of each digit.

```
> '321' - '0'

ans =

     3     2     1
```

Comment: And to add in protection against non-numeric input: vec='321a4'-'0'; vec=vec(vec<10);`

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis for completeness, you can add a `vec>0` to handle all cases, e.g. vec='-321a4&'-'0'; vec=vec(vec<10&vec>0);`

Answer (score 9):

Or, the less cryptic `str2num` or `str2double` applied to each element of the character array

```
arrayfun(@str2double, '321')
```

As a bonus, this will also return `NaN` for string values corresponding to non-scalars, i.e.

```
>> arrayfun(@str2double, '321a')

ans =

     3     2     1   NaN
```

Thus, for string `'321a4'` the following returns only the valid scalars:

```
b = arrayfun(@str2double, '321a4')
c = b(~isnan(b))
c =

 3     2     1     4
```

Comment: Instead of `arrayfun`, you can simply transpose the array before calling `str2double`: out = str2double(string')';`

Comment: @Jonas will only work for `str2num` though, and will crash for both, if one string value corresponds to a non-scalar.

Comment: good point. Anyway, I much prefer `str2double` to the subtraction 'trick'. +1

Comment: @Jonas doing 10.000 trial runs gave `str2double+arrayfun`: 5.7sec, subtraction "trick": 0.06sec. Regardless of your preferences, you'll have to come up with exceptionally good reasons not to use it :)

Comment: @Jonas: Then hide the code you don't like inside a function.  e.g. `digit2double`.  Then you get speed and clean calling code.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(*str)
{

    value [i]=  (*str - '0');
    start++;
    i++;

}
```