# how do i do a specific conversion for a text of data to integers in matlab?

Tags: function, matlab, rsa

I am trying to convert a text of data to integers to do RSA encryption.
For example a word such as cat would be translated to 30120.
where 3 is c, 01 is a, and 20 is t.

so each letter matches up with an integer starting from 1 to 26, where 26 is z.

Comment: Start here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12255083/103167

Comment: I think you'll want to think this one through a bit more. Are there any spaces in this text? Any carriage returns or tabs? Any punctuation or numbers?

Comment: for simplicity first, there will not be any spaces, punctuation, or capital letters.

Answer (score 1):

The intrinsic function `double` will convert a string to a sequence of integers representing the character codes of the elements in the string.  So, for example:

```
double('cat')
```

returns

```
99    97   116
```

A little arithmetic will get you the numbers you want.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you something to start with.

```
abc = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
word = 'cat';
str = '';
for i = 1:length(word); 
    idx = strfind(abc, word(i));
    str = [str,num2str(idx,'%02d')]
end
num = str2double(str)
```

Comment: If it matters, I believe you might be able to do this without the loop if you used strfind correctly and could figure out a way to build 'str' without the loop, but that would take a bit of playing around.