# Breaking up a string and then converting to a vector?

Tags: arrays, string, matlab

If I have three strings, such as `'Y20194'`, `'219Y42'`, and `'12345'` how do I break these up into a vector like `[Y 2 0 1 9 4]`, `[1 2 3 4 5]`, and `[2 1 9 Y 4 2]`? I am using `str2num`, but I think I am missing a step (separating the individual numbers in the strings first) before I convert to numerical values. Also, the characters aren't reading correctly and using `str2num` gives me [].

I have a file with lines of strings such as the one above. I used `fgetl` to read each line of my file into strings but am kind of stuck beyond that.

Comment: converting a string to an array of scalar values (has been answered before): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12255056/matlab-converting-the-string-321-to-3-2-1?lq=1 How do you want to handle the non-numeric values though, i.e. what will `Y` above be in the resulting array?

Comment: I have a file of strings and I wanted to read them into a matrix and change the Ys into 0s. I am using `fgetl` to read my file in, and then I'm stuck at how to read these strings into vectors since I was thinking that once I am able to transform these strings into vectors, I can use `find` to change the Ys to 0s like I'd like.

Comment: as in the above, linked answer you can go with something like `s = 'Y20194'; v = arrayfun(@str2double, s); v(isnan(v)) = 0;`, that will convert the non-numerical values to `0` (or any value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The char will be kept. and the numbers will be converted to double type.

If the input is not from reading a file, the code is as follows. The result1 is the cell containing the array you want:

[image]

If the input is one file, let's take this file as example: demo1.txt, which content as follows:
[image]

the codes to convert each line to what you want as follows. the code converts each line into what you want and then display it.

[image]

If you want to replace the 'Y' or other alphabets with zero, then the code will be as follows

[image]

Comment: Ah yes, the second one is what I'm looking for. Thank you! What if after I have read it into a cell array, I want to convert the 'Y's into a numbers. For example, after I've read in the file of strings, I want to change all the Ys to 0s? Would I just use the `find` command to replace the Ys with 0s? I know that would work for a normal numeric vector but would it work for a cell array too?

Comment: Hi, I have updated the answer. See the last figure. If you want to 'array' instead of 'cell', you can change Line 11 to be 'result1=[]'. To use 'find' to locate one element in cell, you can refer to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061344/how-to-search-for-a-string-in-cell-array-in-matlab

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have both characters and numbers in a numerical vector.

You can do the following:

```
s = 'Y20194';
c = cellstr(s')';
v = str2double(c);
```

Cell array `c` will have all the characters from `s` separated in to individual cells. Notice that you have to transpose the string `s` first.

In vector `v` the first value will be NaN since it's a character.

Comment: +1 for the good answer, though I think you may want to put that last paragraph as a comment on the other answer.

Comment: Moved last paragraph to a comment. Cleaning up.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [STRSPLIT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html) will help.

```
ts = strsplit('Y20194');
%       ts <- {'Y', '2', '0', '1', '9', '4'}
```

And now you can try to convert each element in the vector individually to a number using str2num.

```
N = size(ts, 1);
str = cell(1, N);
for i=1:N;
    str{i} = str2num(ts{i, 1});
end
```

But since some of the characters in the string aren't numbers (e.g., 'Y'), I wouldn't expect this to work perfectly.

(Its been a while, some of my indexes may be switched.)

Comment: I believe STRSPLIT only appears in the latest version 2013a. And you need additional arguments to split a string to individual characters. See the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the `Y` into `0` a very simple solution is available:

```
str = 'Y20194';
str(str==Y)='0';
str - '0'
```