# Matlab, how to convert a string of integers into a vector?

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [convert string to number array in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046605/convert-string-to-number-array-in-matlab)

Is there a simple way in Matlab to convert a string like this

```
'123456789'
```

into a vector like this ?

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If all you have is contiguous characters from 0 to 9:

```
v = double(s)-'0';
```

double(s) converts a string into an array where each element is the ASCII code of the corresponding character. To obtain the numberic values we subtract '0' (which is in fact 48 in ASCII) and since digits have a sequential representation in ASCII code ('1' = 49, '2' = 50, etc.) we end up with intended result.

Comment: The double doesn't in fact seem to be necessary. s - '0' would suffice. @pedrosorio

Answer (score 5):

one way would be using `regexp` for this. But of course it only works for single digit numbers.

```
>> str = '123456789';
>> num = regexp(str,'\d')

num =

 1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
```