# Converting char to integer at matlab

Tags: matlab, type-conversion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [convert string to number array in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046605/convert-string-to-number-array-in-matlab)

I have a vector y including values `'1' '2' '3'` char values and I want to convert it to a corresponding integer vector. If I used `str2num` it gives `49 50 51` like numbers. How could I do it ?

Comment: Could you explain how you get `49 50 51` back from str2num? Something doesn't seem right here.

Comment: @s.bandara: Seems right to me.  Those are the ASCII codes for `'123'`

Comment: But why would `str2num` return those?

Comment: Because `char(['1' '2' '3'])` won't give the ascii values, and then one can just use `intc = int32(str2num(c))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
y - '0'
```

Subtracts the ASCII value for `'0'` from each vector element, taking advantage of the fact that the ASCII values for digits are contiguous.