# How sort ascend string representing numbers?

Tags: matlab, sorting

```
a=cellstr('10');
b=cellstr('5');
a=char(a);
b=char(b);
c={a,b};
d=sort(c);
>>d
  = '10'  '5'
```

I want to get `'5' '10'`. But in this case, it is not ascending....

How can I sort ascending??

Comment: I want to sort number and string. can I sort 'apple' and 'able' by your comment? I'll make binary search tree.

Comment: Strings are sorted in lexicographical order; since '1' comes before '5', this is the order you get. If you want to sort by the corresponding numerical order, you have to convert the strings to numbers. Also, why don't you simply write `c = {'10', '5'};` instead of those five first lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have been clearer in your question instead of adding information in comment.
If I understand right, you want a way to sort numbers AND words all together. Let's take a sample cell array which has all that:

```
c = {'apple';'10';'able';'5'} ;
```

Then the following will sort the array in 2 pass. The first pass will sort the array based on pure ascii value, so the words will be properly sorted but the numbers will still exhibit the behavior you mentionned in your question. The second pass will then take all the string that represent numbers, sort them then put them back into the array.

```
%// First pass, sort the pure text fields
c_half_sorted = cellstr( char(sortrows(double(char(c))))) ;

%// second pass, sort the numbers
c_numbers = cellfun( @(a) sscanf(a,'%f') , c_half_sorted , 'uni',0) ;   %// convert what we can in numbers
isNumber  = cellfun( @(a) ~isempty(a) , c_numbers ) ;                   %// index what has been converted
%// sort numbers and convert back to string/cell
c_num = strtrim (cellstr( num2str( sort( cell2mat( c_numbers(isNumber) ) ,'ascend')))) ;   

%// Merge sorted numbers and words
c_sorted = [ c_num ; c_half_sorted(size(c_num,1)+1:end) ] ;
```

The result mid-way is :

```
c_half_sorted = 
    '10'
    '5'
    'able'
    'apple'
```

Then after the second pass:

```
c_sorted = 
    '5'
    '10'
    'able'
    'apple'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer for you. Here [it](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/4684#answer_6509) is

There is a bunch of type conversions and sorting. Regarding to your example it may be done as follows

```
C = {'30', 'a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e', '1'};
a=str2double(C);
characters=C(isnan(a));
Str = sprintf('%s', characters{:});
numar=Str-0;
[~, index] = sort(numar);
characters = characters(index);

numbers=C(~isnan(a));
numbers = sort(numbers);
C=[numbers, characters];
```

The result is `C = '1'    '30'    'a'    'e'    'l'    'p'    'p'` 
The trick is in the fifth line where I convert chars to numbers. Here is more info regarding decoding of [chars to numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14147888/converting-char-to-integer-at-matlab)

Comment: I have corrected the answer

Comment: It doesn't work string like 'apple ,'able'.  I think this code operates on number only. But Thanks alot!

Comment: Hmm... your first code is operating on number. and modified code is operationg on string, but not in number.
I want to opearting either sting and number.

Comment: It is not true. It operates on both, see example

Comment: >> d=cellstr('10');
>> d=char(d);
>> e=cellstr('5');
>> e=char(e);
>> C = {d,e};
Str = sprintf('%s,', C{:});
numar=Str-0;
numar=numar(find(numar~=44));
[dummy, index] = sort(C);
sortedC = C(index)

sortedC = 

    '10'    '5'

my matlab's answer is....

Comment: Now it should work, check the sound